# setfacl changes not sticking after file is rotated

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am monitoring a file in a directory called /var/log/appname with Zabbix. To give the 'zabbix' user/zabbix-agent permission to the directory, and a particular log file inside the directory, I resorted to using extended file attributes:

```
setfacl -R -m mask:r-x,d:mask:r--,u:zabbix:r-x,d:u:zabbix:r-- /var/log/appname/file.log
```

`getfacl` output looks fine but soon as the application rotates the file, and creates a new one, the default permissions that should be inherited aren't.

Before rotating, and after applying the attributes to the directory:

```
# file: /var/log/appname
# owner: appuser
# group: appuser
user::rwx
user:zabbix:r-x
group::rwx          #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:zabbix:r--
default:group::rwx      #effective:r--
default:mask::r--
default:other::r-x
```

After the file is rotated, the new file has the following attributes:

```
# file: /var/log/appname/file.log
# owner: appname
# group: appname
user::rw-
user:zabbix:r--         #effective:---
group::rwx          #effective:---
mask::---
other::---
```

I am at the point where I just want to give up and run `crontab` to `chmod` the log directory and file.log.

Comment: I ended up doing to the crontab hack. Still wonder why facl doesn't behave the way it is supposed to.